# limit of division with 2 square roots

Tags: calculus

I know how to deal with limits with one square root. But I have no idea how one would deal with a limit of a square root devided by a different square root, like this one:
[limit of division with 2 square roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CjLB.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there isn't a root nested in the other root, you can treat them independently:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-3}{4-\sqrt{2x}}=\frac{x+1-9}{\sqrt{x+1}+3}\,\frac{4+\sqrt{2x}}{16-2x}=-\frac12\frac{4+\sqrt{2x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+3}\to -\frac43\enspace \text{ as } \;x\to 8.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply L'Hopital's rule here.